# Why am I getting cdiscount error "connect ECONNREFUSED"

Tags: econnrefused

I tried several times to register to cdiscount at https://dev.cdiscount.com/docs/gettingStarted so I can get the API key for my site. However, I keep getting the following error:

connect ECONNREFUSED

Could someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Provide an example source code and console log or equivalent so that people can understand better / reproduce.

Comment: If you registered you should have gotten an API key that you most likely have to send with every request. Your Error is basically saying that they are denying you the right to connect most likely because you aren't providing the key or another security measure such as your APP hasn't been authorized.

Comment: I'm unable to register a new account at the link provided above. I can only apply for the API key after I'm able to successfully register.

Comment: What doesn't allow you to register?

Comment: The form on https://dev.cdiscount.com/register is not accepting my registration request. I keep getting the error.